# Adding class to Angular2 component HTML markup does not apply the styles

Tags: html, css, angular

In Angular2, when I add a class tag on my custom Angular2 component like so:

```
<my-component class="someClass"></my-component>
```

...the styling does not get applied to the HTML. In Chrome Developer tools, when I select my-component element, the styles inspector shows that the styles are being applied, but visually, they are not. Is this normal? How do I get around that?

Comment: Post the component decorator part, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass any thing like className then use bindings:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-component',
 template: template,
 styleUrls: ['app/components/nav-bar/nav-bar.style.css'], // or you can add explicit style,
bindings:{
  className: '<'
}  
})
```

HTML

```
 <my-component class-name="someClass"></my-component>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Angular2 throws an error when I did this: Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; styleUrls: string[]; bindings: { className: string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'bindings' does not exist in type 'Component'.

Answer (score 4):

Angular 2 use Shadow DOM, that is part of the Web Components standard and enables DOM tree and style encapsulation.
[Angular View Encapsulation](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html)

So if you want to style something in my-component you should write your class's in my-component class.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    teamplte: '<h1 class="myClass">i am my-component</h1>',
    styles: [`
      .myClass {
         someProp: value;
      }
    `]
})

export class ConatinerComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

but if you want to style outside you must to write your styles and classes in container component!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    teamplte: '<my-component class="myClass"></my-component>',
    styles: [`
      .myClass {
         someProp: value;
      }
    `]
})

export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use this method? All you need is to add some styles to your `my-component`.

CSS

```
my-component {
   background: black;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

And of course, in your component to add html code

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work for me on Chrome (or any other browser). I get the same problem as is my original question: Developer tools tells me the style is there, but visually, it's not.